# Dynamically create ng-table directive from another directive on same element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create wrapper directive for ng-table directive. My wrapper should instantiate ng-table directive on same element as the first directive is applied to and add some custom configuration to ng-table.

I am using following code to create ng-table directive.

```
angular.module('main')
.directive('mkTable', function($compile) {
    return {
        'link': function ($scope, element, attributes) {
            element.removeAttr('mk-table'); // Must remove attribute because of recursion
            element.attr('ng-table', 'tableParams');

            $compile(element)($scope);
        }
    }
})
```

It does create ng-table (you can see it by pagination) but it doesn't display any data. If you check console output you can see that `getData()` function is called.

I presume that problem is in compiling child elements (`tr, td`) and bounding it to new ng-table scope, but I was not able to find the solution.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/1aEAdr2ugl39WG9Ay0vN

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is `ng-repeat` on `tr` element is being compiled couple of times, so I did a little naughty trick :) -insert "fake" to break Angular binding-

```
<tr fake-ng-repeat="user in $data">
  <td data-title="'Name'">{fake{user.name}}</td>
  <td data-title="'Age'">{fake{user.age}}</td>
</tr>
```

Then in the directive remove all "fake(s)" before recompiling:

```
element.html(element.html().replace(/fake-?/g, ''));
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/KJtQifnjwAjy1L2Tp09V?p=preview).

Although it's working, I believe it's dirty trick.

Comment: Indeed that is a dirty trick :) and I would like to solve it more cleanly if it's posible.

Comment: @mersadk actually the problem is when you put `ng-repeat="user in $data"` at first time in your scope there is no `$data` so Angular simply removes that "repeated" element, I think the only thing to prevent that is to break Angular repeat.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of experimenting I figured it out. Solution is to use compile function insted of link.

```
angular.module('main')
.directive('mkTable', function($compile) {
    return {
        compile: function(element, attributes) {
            element.removeAttr('mk-table');
            element.attr('ng-table', 'tableParams');

            var compileFn = $compile(element);

            return function($scope, element, attributes) {
                compileFn($scope);
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Updated demo: http://plnkr.co/vL4kg0KVp4GYEDpOlIrm